# How can I have infinite nested list in CSS to be uniquely styled?

Tags: html, css

For example these codes.

```
.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul ul a {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 45px;
}
```

I want for additional (any amount) `<ul>` to have additional `15px` in left padding. How can I achieve this instead of manually type it?

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: Not sure, but I think CSS preprocessors like SASS have some loop syntax, maybe that's a suitable solution. In any case, *infinite* will be a bit of a problem in any case...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd68t6op/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you want each nested-list to be indented further than the parent?

Here I have placed the padding on the `ul`. This will indent each list 15px relative to its parent.

```css
.sidebar-nav .metismenu {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ADB5BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a:hover {
  color: #F8F9FA;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a:before {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-out;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a:hover:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0B7285;
  height: 3em;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-out, 0.3s color ease-out;
  transform: translateY(-1em);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-nav">
  <div class="metismenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub-item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a>Item 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub-item</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub-item</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Sub-subitem</a></li>
              <li><a>Sub-subitem</a></li>
              <li><a>Sub-subitem</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is sorta good, but not what I want. If you look here, https://jsfiddle.net/yd68t6op/. Your solution prevent `:hover` background to be stretched through the width.

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question. However, I have added the basic `:hover` effect as demonstrated in the fiddle.